# JavaScript generated form input not working

Tags: javascript, php, input

I am generating a form with javascript and PHP but the radio inputs don't work. I'm clicking the radio button and it isn't checking. What is wrong in my code?

```
    function showMenu()
    {
        ...
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("game").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","GetGameMenu.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

here is the echo from GetGameMenu.php:

```
<?php

echo '<form id="menuGame" action="GetGame.php" method="post" onSubmit="showGame(); return false;">
        <div id = "bigDiv">
            <div class="divs">
                <label>SELECT DIFICULTY</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" id="easy" name="dificulty"/>
                    <label for="easy">Easy</label>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        <input type="submit" class="buton" id="butPlay" value="PLAY">
    </form>';
?>
```

I found out that the problem was the css style. I had position:relative and now I put position:absolute and it works.

Answer (score 1):

remove return false from onsubmit event of the form. It should be as below.

```
<form id="menuGame" action="GetGame.php" method="post" onSubmit="showGame();">
```

also make sure that the method `showGame()` does not return false. Then the form will be submitted successfully.

Comment: I removed the return false but it still doesn't work. if i click on the PLAY button the function showGame(); is called and the game is displayed. I need to choose the difficulty of the game but the radio button still doesn't work ...